# str_replace not working with wordpress title

Tags: php, wordpress

Been doing some googling and playing around with this code, and I've been banging my head against a wall for a few hours trying to figure out why this isn't working.

Setting a few variables, the goal is to set a title like "Let's Talk About Stuff", and have the page spit out "`<span>`Let's Talk About`</span>` Stuff"so a few words in the title are highlighted through css. The code I currently have is:

```
$wptitle = get_the_title();
$str = "Let's Talk About";
$rplc = "<span>Let's Talk About</span>";
$title = str_replace($str, $rplc, $wptitle);
```

In the HTML of the page

```
<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
```

This returns the title without the span tags added. I can paste the title into the str_replace instead of $wptitle, and things turn out properly, so my assumption is that it has something to do with get_the_title() spitting out something that isn't quite compatible with str_replace.

Is there another wordpress function I should be using for this instead, or do I need to do something to get_the_title in order for it to work?

Comment: Can you do an `echo $wptitle` so we can see whats actually being returned by `get_the_title()`

Comment: You have assigned the value to `$rplc` but using `$rlpc` in `str_replace()`.

Comment: Performance wise, it is better to do these type of things in the template

Comment: echo $wptitle returns the title as it is entered in the wordpress back end, and I checked the code in the template file, $rplc is what both are written as, editing the original question to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest trying the alternate escaped representations of the apostrophe. My installation allows apostrophes to be directly entered into the database but does escape other punctuation marks. N.B. using echo does not show the raw value as the browser would process it as HTML and replace HTML escape sequences with their target symbol. Try:

```
$wptitle = get_the_title();
$str = ["Let's Talk About", "Let&apos;s Talk About", "Let&#39;s Talk About"];
$rplc = "<span>Let's Talk About</span>";
$title = str_replace($str, $rplc, $wptitle);
```

If you want to see the raw value of a variable, you should use PHP's error_log() function. Unfortunately, this requires you to know how to access PHP's error log. This is not hard but may be different for different installations. If you must use echo then try:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($value);
```

This insures that the browser does not replace HTML escape sequences with their targets.

Comment: This dude right here knows how to str_replace :)

Initially, "Let's Talk About", "Let&apos;s Talk About", "Let&#39;s Talk About" didn't work, but I tried htmlspecialchars to see what was being sent. The proper string to search for was:

Let&#8217;s Talk About

Thanks, I got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to use `str_replace()` here? just wrap your title value with `<span></span>` tag?

```
$wptitle = get_the_title();
if($wptitle != '') {
  $title = '<span>'. $wptitle .'</span>';
}
```

Comment: Because the OP is trying to wrap specific words in the span, not the whole title. This doesn't solve their issue.